# Trying to install WiFi drivers, nothing is working

Tags: networking, drivers, system-installation

My main OS is Windows. I have a MSI MAG X570 motherboard with onboard Wifi. I actually have installed Ubuntu on this exact machine before, and it worked out of the box (Wifi and all).

However, I recently reinstalled Ubuntu, and now I'm having WiFi issues. I downloaded the ISO (Desktop 22.04.3 LTS) from ubuntu.com and used Rufus to create install media. I did a full installation, and checked the box to install additional proprietary software (note: I did choose to create partitions manually, but I doubt it makes any difference). After installation, there was no option for WiFi in the settings. I checked "Additional drivers" and found nothing.

Ethernet is not an option for me, so I tried to get internet by tethering my phone (It's a Samsung Galaxy that's a few years old at least). I'm pretty sure I did everything correctly, and Ubuntu recognized it was connected (plus I know my phone had data), but I still seemed to be unable to connect to the internet.

Now I'm facing the prospect of having to find the right drivers and dependencies, load them onto a flash drive from Windows, then try to install them. Knowing my inexperience with Linux, and how much trouble I run into installing anything complex, I think that will be extremely difficult for me.

Does anyone else have any last ditch suggestions? At this point I'm considering trying another distro and praying it comes bundled with the right drivers.

Edit: As per graham's instructions, I tried using the Try Ubuntu option from the installation media. The Wifi worked right away, and after installing Ubuntu from the desktop shortcut and rebooting, it's still working. Thanks for the help!

Comment: FYI:  You gave no clues as to what Ubuntu product/release you were using before on that hardware, as Ubuntu 22.04 LTS is a LTS release, there is kernel stack choice which is decided at install by the media used. You didn't specify what 22.04.3 (Server? or Desktop?) but if it was me I'd contrast the stack used before (*unspecified*) with what you're using now (22.04.3 will use 5.15 Linux or 6.2 depending on ISO you didn't specify; I'm guessing 6.2 & Desktop)... Other *distros* don't change much in my experience outside of stack age (*ie. what did you use before is key to issue; not Ubuntu*)

Comment: I'm using the desktop release. Unfortunately I have no idea what I was using before. I reformatted my SSD over a year ago, and haven't had Ubuntu installed since then.

Comment: did you use the `Try Ubuntu` option with the USB you created as opposed to install and what was the result? [edit] your response in to your question - don't add to the comment trail...

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was re-installing, but this time clicking the "Try Ubuntu" option. Then I clicked the "Install Ubuntu" icon on the desktop and proceeded to install from there. Thanks to graham for the suggestion.